# Does tinyweb web server allow directly accessing a file?

Tags: webserver, http

I go to https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/ I download the latest tinyweb.

I make a directory called folder

```
C:\tinyweb2018>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

 Directory of C:\tinyweb2017

21/02/2018  02:49 AM    <DIR>          .
21/02/2018  02:49 AM    <DIR>          ..
21/02/2018  02:49 AM                 0 access_log
21/02/2018  02:49 AM                 0 agent_log
21/02/2018  02:47 AM            12,735 cgitest.zip
21/02/2018  02:49 AM                 0 error_log
21/02/2018  02:47 AM                69 file_id.diz
21/02/2018  02:48 AM    <DIR>          folder
21/02/2018  02:47 AM             2,175 licence.txt
21/02/2018  02:47 AM                73 readme.txt
21/02/2018  02:49 AM                 0 referer_log
21/02/2018  02:47 AM           149,124 src.zip
21/02/2018  02:47 AM            77,736 tiny.exe
              10 File(s)        241,912 bytes
```

I run the tinyweb web server
    `C:\tinyweb2017>tiny folder 8002<ENTER>`

I make a file `.\folder\index.html`

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
abc
</body>
</html>
```

I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8002`

It shows fine.

I then do  `http://127.0.0.1:8002/index.html`

And it says  Forbidden

[image]

wget shows headers but gives me no clues other than it's a 403 Forbidden

```
C:\blah>wget 127.0.0.1:8002/index.html -d
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow/etc/wgetrc
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.11.4 on Windows-MinGW.

--2018-02-21 02:54:14--  http://127.0.0.1:8002/index.html
seconds 0.00, Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8002... seconds 0.00, connected.
Created socket 180.
Releasing 0x009495e0 (new refcount 0).
Deleting unused 0x009495e0.

---request begin---
GET /index.html HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.11.4
Accept: */*
Host: 127.0.0.1:8002
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Connection: Close
Server: TinyWeb/1.94
Content-Length: 72
Content-Type: text/html

---response end---
403 Forbidden
Closed fd 180
2018-02-21 02:54:14 ERROR 403: Forbidden.


C:\blah>
```

I've read of this kind of an issue accessing files directly here where somebody was presumably using apache. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16460/403-forbidden-access-when-accessing-custom-html-php-files-directly   And apparently maybe apache has an `.htaccess` file that lets you configure it to allow accessing files directly.  Though tinyweb doesn't seem to.

So is that the issue.. That tinyweb doesn't have such an option?  If so i'll have to find an alternative small web server, or a big one like apache.

Or perhaps there is a way with tinyweb?

Comment: I'll check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050851/best-lightweight-web-server-only-static-content-for-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

To fix this issue, you need to specify the full path of the folder you wish to use as your html root directory when starting TinyWeb e.g.:

```
tiny "C:\tinyweb2017\folder" 8002
```

**Explanation (?)**

Normally, `403 Forbidden` errors occur when you do not have permission to access a particular resource.

While not explicitly mentioned in the TinyWeb [Installing](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/install.php) page, it seems that using a relative path (e.g. `folder` vs `C:\tinyweb2017\folder`) for the root html directory causes TinyWeb to form a bad path (or something similar), making any page that isn't labeled `index.html` return `403 Forbidden` as well as preventing direct access to all pages (e.g. `localhost:8002/index.html`).

---

*TinyWeb appears to return `403 Forbidden` for non-existent paths or items generally.*

---

Comment: re profile and its comments re  reputation..  a few reasons to consider it..well, why perception can matter..two scenarios-  1. having a rep that matches your skillset is helpful so you don't lose opportunities 2. if a girl has a great body but is influenced by status, and you don't want her as a life partner but just to give her a test drive, then it'd help you to use her 'shallowness' to your advantage and impress her.

Comment: @barlop Lol I am pleased you've read my profile. =) Regarding perception, you make excellent points. Perceptions matter, especially in the scenarios you mention. That said, the song (for me, anyway) is more a reminder that perceptions vary greatly from person to person. So if you are defining yourself entirely by others opinions, everyone is likely to be disappointed. =P